# Simplification idea to separate variables

Tags: calculus

How can I make the r.h.s solely dependent on x(i.e. a function of x)? We have 
$$ a = \exp(-x/b) x$$

I tried taking the log on both sides, but I face a similar wall in the simiplification, namely:
$$ln(a)=ln(x)-x/b$$ still cannot get rid of b on the r.h.s.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change variables to $u = -x/b$, so that $x = -bu$, and then you have 
$$ a = -\exp(u)bu $$
so
$$ -a/b = u\exp(u) $$
If you would like to solve for $u$, use the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
$$ u = W(-a/b) $$
(of course, you will have to be careful about domains and branches and such).

Once we have done this, we can reverse the variable transformation to find $x$: 
$$ x = -bu = -bW(-a/b) $$

Comment: Neat. There's no other way to get rid of the b on the rhs without emplying the lambert function?

Comment: @user929304 By the time we have $-a/b = u\exp(u)$ we have already gotten rid of the $b$ on the rhs. The Lambert function is just icing on the cake in case you want to solve the whole thing for $u$.

Comment: But by a change of var we ve only hidden b in u and not rly gotten rid of it, right?

Comment: @user929304 Ahh, no! This is a subtle but very important point. When we solve an equation by manipulation, e.g. passing from $x + 3 = 5$ to $x = 2$ by subtracting $3$ from both sides, we are in fact *replacing* the original equation by a *new* equation with the same solution set. The same principle applies here: we are replacing the original equation with a new, simpler equation, and once we find the solution set of the new equation, we will be able to transform it to find the solution set of the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept a solution using the [Lambert $W$ Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) multiply both sides by $\frac{-1}{b}$ to get:

$$-\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{x}{b}\exp(-\frac{x}{b})$$

Hence:

$$-\frac{x}{b}=W(-\frac{a}{b})$$

$$x=-bW(-\frac{a}{b})$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd like to emphasize that I don't want to solve for x here, but only intend to get rid of the b on the rhs. Does that make any difference? Or does it boil down to what you ve done?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean @user929304